# Is there any way to fetch details of tapped activity type in Share sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented share functionality and after completion of it I just want to navigate to next page which works fine but for one case which is message, I want to hit an api but that api requires phone number of the tapped user. It’s like I open the share sheet, I tap on any random contact or tap message to create new one and after completion call the api and pass the phone number of tapped user or the user who I shared content with. I’m not able to access that.Is there any way to do that as after completion all I’m able to use is whether is completed or not. I read documentation and saw we can return some data printed items, they were nill too. It does tell after tapping a contact that it was message type but wont give me more data. Here is the code that I have done so far:

```
private func presentShareSheet() {
    let url = "appUrl"
    let customText = "Click this link: \(url)"
        
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [customText], applicationActivities: nil)
        
    // Exclude certain activity types if needed
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        .airDrop,
        .addToReadingList,
        .assignToContact,
        .markupAsPDF,
        .openInIBooks,
        .print,
        .saveToCameraRoll
    ]
        
    // Set the completion handler for the activity view controller
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] activityType, completed, returnedItems, _ in
        if completed {
            self?.handleShareSheetCompletion()
        } else {
            // User canceled the activity view controller, handle the cancellation here
            self?.handleShareSheetCancellation()
        }
    }
        
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is there any way to get details of the contact that I tapped on the share sheet or typed after clicking new message?

Comment: No, you can't know anything about the recipient. It would be a privacy violation.

Comment: @Paulw11 When we use contact picker, we can fetch phone number after tapping a contact so I assumed there might be some way to do that here. I read the documentation and so far only thing we can tell is which type of activity was tapped, nothing more. Thanks for clarifying that we cannot fetch anymore data than that

Comment: The user explicitly grants your app access to their contacts before you can use a contact picker. A share extension is not granted this access